# Weird "#/" at the end of URL locally

Tags: laravel, vue.js, url, xampp, localhost

I am messing around locally with a laravel and vue project, I also have vue-router setup but my URL look like this: `<virtual-host>.loc/#/`.

Whenever I access my v-host it loads but I get this weird `#/` thing appended to the end of the URL. Does anybody know where it comes from? Is it a JS thing?

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode

Comment: wow thanks! Although after switching, a whole new set of problems occur like after refresh you get 404. I'll just stick with the # sign in the URL. thanks

Answer (score 0):

by default vue js use hash mode. that's why you see that type of url. to change this behavior you need to  set mode property to history like this,

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```